# Understanding 'arguments' definition in gnu-assembly

Tags: assembly, integer, arguments, gnu-assembler, twos-complement

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what the following means from the [`as arguments page`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Arguments.html#Arguments):

> Symbols are evaluated to yield {section NNN} where section is one of text, data, bss, absolute, or undefined. NNN is a signed, 2’s complement 32 bit integer.

What would be an example of `section NNN` ? Is `text`, `data`, etc a data type or is that the literal word that is used in the context? Finally, why does it mention a *signed, **2's complement** 32 bit integer* ? Aren't all 32 bit integers 2's complement (at least ones that are in programming usage?)

Comment: There _is_ also 1’s complement and even BCD. 2’s complement is merely ubiquitous these days. AFAIK, C is an example of a language that doesn’t require/mandate either bit 1-or-2 complement representation.

Comment: *Aren't all 32 bit integers 2's complement* - no, historically platforms have existed that used 1's complement and even sign/magnitude natively.  C allows those as possible representations for signed integer types, making it possible for C to run efficiently on such hardware.  Also of course, software and file formats could use other encodings, especially if it's useful to have a "sentinel" value that's special.  So documentation has to specify that.  AFAIK GNU systems always use 2's complement as their native hardware integer format for signed values, e.g. GCC is only portable to such HW.

Comment: Also, in case it's not obvious, of course `unsigned` integers are in widespread usage.  Pure binary place-value, no special "sign" bit with a different meaning.  So even on mainstream x86 CPUs, it's easy to have an integer that isn't 2's complement, but instead unsigned.  I think you meant to say "aren't all 32-bit signed integers 2's complement?".

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the explanation that makes sense. Yes, regarding `signed`.